# How to check if file exists in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, file-exists

I have a script where I want to check if a file exists in a bucket and if it doesn't then create one.

I tried using `os.path.exists(file_path)` where `file_path = "/gs/testbucket"`, but I got a file not found error.

I know that I can use the `files.listdir()` API function to list all the files located at a path and then check if the file I want is one of them. But I was wondering whether there is another way to check whether the file exists.

Comment: +1 ran into this myself. We eventually wound up doing an HTTP HEAD on the public address of the file, but that's not a general solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is no function to check directly if the file exists given its path.
I have created a function that uses the `files.listdir()` API function to list all the files in the bucket and match it against the file name that we want. It returns true if found and false if not.

Answer (score 75):

This post is old, you can actually now check if a file exists on GCP using the blob class, but because it took me a while to find an answer, adding here for the others who are looking for a solution

```
from google.cloud import storage

name = 'file_i_want_to_check.txt'   
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket_name = 'my_bucket_name'
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
stats = storage.Blob(bucket=bucket, name=name).exists(storage_client)
```

Documentation is [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html)

Hope this helps!

### Edit

As per the comment by @om-prakash, if the file is in a folder, then the name should include the path to the file:

```py
name = "folder/path_to/file_i_want_to_check.txt"
```

Comment: Above solution may not work if file exist in some folder in google cloud storage and not in root directory of cloud storage, do this instead `stats = storage.Blob(bucket=bucket, name="folder_1/another_folder_2/your_file.txt").exists(storage_client)`

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: it will also not work if the blob is a folder and not a file.

Comment: the link has been moved: 

https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob#google_cloud_storage_blob_Blob_exists

Answer (score 35):

It's as easy as use the exists method within a blob object:

```
from google.cloud import storage

def blob_exists(projectname, credentials, bucket_name, filename):
   client = storage.Client(projectname, credentials=credentials)
   bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
   blob = bucket.blob(filename)
   return blob.exists()
```

Comment: For thousands of URLs this is slow.  Is there anyway to submit a batch of key/buckets in one go?

Comment: also seems error prone if the file is large (anecdotal). `urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))`

Answer (score 15):

The answer provided by @nickthefreak is correct, and so is the comment by Om Prakash. One other note is that the bucket_name should not include `gs://` in front or a `/` at the end.

Piggybacking off @nickthefreak's example and Om Prakash's comment:

```
from google.cloud import storage

name = 'folder1/another_folder/file_i_want_to_check.txt'   

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket_name = 'my_bucket_name'  # Do not put 'gs://my_bucket_name'
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
stats = storage.Blob(bucket=bucket, name=name).exists(storage_client)
```

stats will be a Boolean (True or False) depending on whether the file exists in the Storage Bucket.

(I don't have enough reputation points to comment, but I wanted to save other people some time because I wasted way too much time with this).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. 

`.exists()` does not require that extra arg.

Answer (score 8):

If you are looking for a solution in NodeJS, then here it is:

```
var storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
var myBucket = storage.bucket('my-bucket');

var file = myBucket.file('my-file');

file.exists(function(err, exists) {});

// If the callback is omitted, then this function return a Promise.
file.exists().then(function(data) {
  var exists = data[0];
});
```

If you need more help, you can refer to this doc:
https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.5.x/File#exists

Comment: OP specifically asked for Python

Answer (score 4):

If you're working with gcs files on a service like "Google AI Platform", use tensorflow to check whether a file exists or not:

```
import tensorflow as tf
file_exists = tf.gfile.Exists('gs://your-bucket-name/your-file.txt')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the stat function to get a files info. This will in practice do a HEAD request to google cloud storage instead of a GET, which is a bit less resource intensive.

```
import cloudstorage as gcs
# return stat if there is one, else None or false. A stat record should be truthy
def is_file_available(filepath):

  try:
    return gcs.stat(filepath)
  except gcs_errors.NotFoundError as e:
    return False
```

Answer (score 2):

The file I am searching on google cloud storage: init.sh

**Full path:** gs://cw-data/spark_app_code/init.sh

```
>>> from google.cloud import storage

>>> def is_exist(bucket_name,object):
...     client = storage.Client()
...     bucket = client.bucket(bucket_name)
...     blob = bucket.get_blob(object)
...     try:
...             return blob.exists(client)
...     except:
...             return False
...
>>> is_exist('cw-data','spark_app_code')
    False
>>> is_exist('cw-data','spark_app_code/')
    True
>>> is_exist('cw-data','init.sh')
    False
>>> is_exist('cw-data','spark_app_code/init.sh')
    True
>>> is_exist('cw-data','/init.sh')
    False
>>>
```

Here, the files are not stored in the way they are stored on local filesystems rather they are stored as keys. So, while searching the file on google storage use absolute path rather than just filename.

Answer (score 1):

Slight variation on Amit's answer from a few years ago, updated for the cloudstorage api.

```
import cloudstorage as gcs

def GCSExists(gcs_file):
    '''
    True if file exists; pass complete /bucket/file
    '''
    try:
        file = gcs.open(gcs_file,'r')
        file.close()
        status = True
    except:
        status = False
    return status
```

Comment: ```import cloudstorage as gcs
gcs.open("gs://foo/foo.bar")
AttributeError: module 'cloudstorage' has no attribute 'open'```

Answer (score 1):

Yes! It posible! [from this](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html)

And this is my code:

```
def get_by_signed_url(self, object_name, bucket_name=GCLOUD_BUCKET_NAME):
    bucket = self.client_storage.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(object_name)

    #this is check if file exist or not
    stats = blob.exists(self.client_storage)
    if not stats:
        raise NotFound(messages.ERROR_NOT_FOUND)

    url_lifetime = self.expiration  # Seconds in an hour
    serving_url = blob.generate_signed_url(url_lifetime)
    return self.session.get(serving_url)
```

Comment: Though there is a file in the bucket this always returns 'False' for me.

Comment: @AjitK'sagar me not. If file exist gcs will return url of file. Maybe your url is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

from google.cloud import storage

```
def if_file_exists(name:str,bucket_name:str):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    stats = storage.Blob.from_string(f"gs://{bucket_name}/{name}").exists(storage_client)
    return stats
```

print(if_file_exists('audios/courses/ActivityPlaying/1320210506130438.wav',GC_BUCKET_NAME),">>>")

> **name** args is the remaining path of the file

if_file_exists function takes two positional args first one is the object key and second is the bucket name and return true if file exists else false

Comment: this is useful if you want to accept full file path as an input argument and want to validate if the file exists

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom function (shown below) to check file exists or not

```
def is_file_available(filepath):
 #check if the file is available
 fileavability = 'yes';
 try: 
  fp = files.open(filepath, 'r')
  fp.close()
 except Exception,e:
  fileavability = 'no'
 return fileavability
```

use the above function in following way

```
 filepath = '/gs/test/testme.txt'
 fileavability = is_file_available(filepath)
```

note: in above function you may get also result as 'no' when read permission is not given to the application which is trying to read  the file.

Answer (score 0):

Since the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525482/how-to-check-if-file-exists-in-google-cloud-storage/13644827#13644827) on this question didn't provide much detail - here's a modern solution using `gsutil` that functions as described by that answer.

This becomes more effective than the other answers if you need to query your GCS files many times in your script.

```
def bucket_to_list(bucketname: str):
    '''
    Return bucket's contents to python list of strings. 
    We also slice off the bucket name on each line, 
    in case we need to search many buckets for one file.
    '''
    return subprocess.run(['gsutil','ls','-r', bucketname + '**'], shell=False, text=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.replace(bucketname, "").splitlines()
```

Use in the following way:

```
# call once for each bucket to store bucket contents 
mybucket1 = 'gs://mybucket1/'
mybucket1list = bucket_to_list(mybucket1)

# limiting list to a bucket's "subdirectories"
mybucket2 = 'gs://mybucket2/subdir1/subdir2/'
mybucket2list = bucket_to_list(mybucket2)

# example filename list to check, we dont need to add the gs:// paths 
filestocheck = ['file1.ext', 'file2.ext', 'file3.ext']

# check both buckets for files in our filelist
for file in filestocheck:
    if file in mybucket1list:
        # do something if file exists in bucket1
    elif file in mybucket2list:
        # do something if file exists in bucket2
    else:
        # do something if file doesn't exist in either bucket
```

Comment: I'm not sure that is "modern solution". If you are using python, it's smarter to use GCP API with it.

Comment: Don't call out to a subprocess if native libaries exists